# Change QTableWidgetItem Background Color

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm trying to change the color of the background of an `QTableWidgetItem`. There is some others posts about the same thing but none of the given solutions worked for me.

For each row, I create the `QTableWidgetItems` one by one and I then assign it to cells of current row with setItem.

I tried to change the color just after they have been created with :

1. `self.myTable.myItem1.setBackgroundColor(QtGui.QColor(255,100,0,255))`
2. `self.myTable.myItem1.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(255,100,0,255))`
3. `self.myTable.myItem1.setData(Qt.BackgroundRole,QtGui.QColor(255,100,0,255))`

But these solutions do nothing in my case.
Is there something I am missing ?

Any help is welcome

Comment: How about `self.myTable.myItem1.background().setColor(QtGui.QColor(255,100,0,255))` ?

Comment: It doesn't work either.. :(
I tried :
`font=QtGui.QFont(self)`
`font.setBold(True)`
`self.myTable.myItem1.setFont(font)`

And it works. (but it's not what I want)

Comment: well that was what I was looking for at first.
I currently have a general stylesheet but as I want to color only one `QTableWidgetItem` I wanted to use something like `setObjectName` on my item and assign a special style to this name on my stylesheet but there is no `setObjectName` for `QTableWidgetItem`. Same thing for `setStyleSheet`.

Comment: @OdgyGsf. All three methods work exactly as expected for me (i.e. they change the background colour to red). Please post some simple example code that demonstrates the problem, so that others can try to reproduce it.

Comment: @mdurant Your code is incorrect. `background()` returns `QBrush` by value, so modifying it has no effect.

Answer (score 6):

You have to set the background color of the *item*. There are a few ways to do this (full script is further down):

- Option 1: Set the background on the item, *then* add the item to the table.

In this example, we are setting `item1` to have "row1" as the content. If this is an even row, we then set the background to a light red/pink.

```
item1 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('row1')
if row % 2 == 0:
    item1.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(255, 128, 128))
self.table.setItem(row,0,item1)
```

- Option 2: Set the background on an already existing item in the table. This requires that you operate directly on the item.

In this example, we are setting the background to a light grey on the item are Row 1, Column 0:

```
self.table.item(1,0).setBackground(QtGui.QColor(125,125,125))
```

---

A full script, showing both the red and the grey highlighting is here:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui 
import sys

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(2)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        data1 = ['row1','row2','row3','row4']
        data2 = ['1','2.0','3.00000001','3.9999999']

        self.table.setRowCount(4)

        for row in range(4):
            item1 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(data1[row])
            if row % 2 == 0:
                item1.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(255, 128, 128))
            self.table.setItem(row,0,item1)

        self.table.item(1,0).setBackground(QtGui.QColor(125,125,125))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Output:

[image: Example output showing two methods of highlighting background]

Comment: Ty for the nice post. However, I'm still unable to make it work on my example. I think that the problem comes from my stylesheet. There must be a set color that cannot be overriden or something like this. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone googling this:
QTableWidgetItem.setBackground was not working for me, and that is because i had this as the styleSheet for the table:

```
QTableWidget::item{border: 0px; padding-left: 2px;}
```

i only wanted the `padding-left: 2px` bit, but it does not work without `border: 0px`, so i added it, and it broke: QTableWidgetItem.setBackground.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).